# How to linearise $\dot \epsilon_y = (a+\epsilon_y)(1- \frac{a+\epsilon_y}{a+\epsilon_x})$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, perturbation-theory, fixed-points

I have the following dynamical system

$$\frac{d x}{d \tau}=\gamma x(1-x)-\alpha x y$$
$$\frac{d y}{d \tau}=y\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right),$$
where $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ are constant parameters. I am trying to figure out the stability of the fixed point $(x_0, y_0) = (\frac{\gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}, \frac{\gamma}{\gamma + \alpha})$. I have tried to linearise the system by pluging $x = x_0 + \epsilon_x$ and $y = y_0 + \epsilon_y$ in the system and managed to linearise the ODE for $\dot \epsilon_x$, but for $\dot \epsilon_y$ I got
$$\dot \epsilon_y = (a+\epsilon_y)(1- \frac{a+\epsilon_y}{a+\epsilon_x}),$$
where $a = x_0 = y_0$.

**Question:**

How can I linearise the equation for $\dot \epsilon_y$?

---

I have tried expanding it around $(0,0)$ as a Taylor series, but all the terms of order smaller than $2$ vanish, so I need to deal with terms of order $2$; but that does not help me solving the problem. After all, the  reason why we do linearisation is that we can find the eigenvalues of the linearised system to determine the stability of the fixed points of the non-linearised system.

Comment: Please provide a little more context. By expanding the second factor one finds that the direct linearization is $\dot ϵ_y=(a+0)\frac{ϵ_x-ϵ_y}{a+0}$ for $a\ne 0$. Is there also an equation for $\dot ϵ_x$? Did you compute the Jacobian of the system at the fixed point? Is one eigenvalue zero, what is its eigenvector?

Comment: @LutzLehmann See my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the second factor arithmetically, you get
$$
\dot ϵ_y=(a+ϵ_y)\frac{ϵ_x-ϵ_y}{a+ϵ_x}.
$$
As the difference $ϵ_x-ϵ_y$ is already first-order small, all the other factors need only be expanded to first order. Assuming $a\ne 0$, only the constant term $a$ remains and cancels from the expression. Thus the linearization is
$$
\dot ϵ_y=ϵ_x-ϵ_y.
$$

Comment: The problem doesn't say that $\epsilon_x$ and $\epsilon_y$ are the same order.

Comment: @Paul : They are both the first-order terms in an expansion of $x$ and $y$. This means that the expression you want to find is $O(ϵ_x,ϵ_y)$ while removing everything $$O((ϵ_x,ϵ_y)^2)$.

Comment: If it is not going to be a problem; could you also show how you expanded the second factor because I have tried that many times and didn't get any sensible solution

Comment: There is no truncation happening, just arithmetic manipulation. The first formula is equivalent to the original non-linear formula. It is just $1-\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x-y}{x}$. What remains is not expansion but truncation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann To be completely honest, I don't understand

Comment: @LutzLehmann perturbation theory is more than just Taylor expansions.  There are many cases in multidimensional perturbation theory where the perturbations are of different order in different directions.  You could have $\epsilon_x=O(\epsilon_y^2)$ or $\epsilon_x=O(\sqrt{\epsilon_y})$.  You need this information before you make the assumptions you do here.

Comment: @Paul : No, you don't, at least not in this first stage. Here these two are independently small. In other words, this is just an alternative to computing the Jacobi matrix at the stationary point. If it turns out that the Jacobian is singular, and then one wants to compute the central manifold, then one needs to consider dependencies like that.