# The stability of a fixed point, given that the one of the eigenvalues of the linearised system is zero and the other it negative?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

I have the following dynamical system

$$\frac{d x}{d \tau}=\gamma x(1-x)-\alpha x y$$
$$\frac{d y}{d \tau}=y\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right),$$
where $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ are constant parameters. I am trying to figure out the stability of the fixed point $(x_0, y_0) = (\frac{\gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}, \frac{\gamma}{\gamma + \alpha})$

When I perturb the system around the fixed point such that $x = x_0+ \epsilon_x$ and $y = y_0 + \epsilon_y$, and [linearise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634587/how-to-linearise-dot-epsilon-y-a-epsilon-y1-fraca-epsilon-ya-eps) the system, I get the following jacobian matrix
$$J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha} & -\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Since one of the eigenvalues of this is zero, the linearisation fail, i.e we cannot determine the stability of the fixed point of the non-linear system from the stability of the fixed point of the linear system.

This means that I have to solve the nonlinear system of equation for the perturbations in order to determine the stability of the fixed point,

$$\dot \epsilon_x  = \left(\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}\right)\epsilon_x -  \left(\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}\right)\epsilon_y - \gamma \epsilon_x^2 - \alpha \epsilon_x \epsilon_y$$
$$\dot \epsilon_y = [ \left(\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}\right) + \epsilon_y][1-\frac{ \left(\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}\right) + \epsilon_y}{ \left(\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\gamma + \alpha}\right) + \epsilon_x}].$$

**Question:**

How to find the stability of this fixed point, given that the one of the eigenvalues of the linearised system is zero and the other it negative?

Comment: Do you know anything about center manifold theory?

Comment: @mattos no I don't

Comment: what is the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

The equilibrium points obtained as solutions for

$$
\cases{
\gamma x(1-x)-\alpha x y = 0\\
y(1-\frac yx)=0}
$$

are

$$
\left(1,0\right),\ \ \ \left(\frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\gamma},\frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\gamma}\right)
$$

The jacobian gives

$$
J = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \gamma  (1-x)-\gamma  x-\alpha  y & -\alpha  x \\
 \frac{y^2}{x^2} & 1-\frac{2 y}{x} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and evaluated at the equilibrium points give

$$
J_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\gamma  & -\alpha  \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \ J_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{\gamma ^2}{\alpha +\gamma } & -\frac{\alpha  \gamma }{\alpha +\gamma } \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with the correspoding eigenvalues

$$
(1,\ -\gamma),\ \ \ \ \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\left(\alpha +\gamma ^2+\gamma \right)^2-4 \gamma  (\alpha +\gamma )^2}+\alpha +\gamma ^2+\gamma
   }{2 (\alpha +\gamma )},-\frac{-\sqrt{\left(\alpha +\gamma ^2+\gamma \right)^2-4 \gamma  (\alpha +\gamma
   )^2}+\alpha +\gamma ^2+\gamma }{2 (\alpha +\gamma )}\right)
$$

so normally, no zero eigenvalues.